# Amarok fails to start

Tags: amarok

After last `Amarok` update on `Archlinux` I get this error:

`The name org.kde.amarok was not provided by any .service files`

I can start `Amarok` from terminal but clicking its icon on latte-dock gives me this error.

Desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Qt;KDE;AudioVideo;Audio;Player;
Comment=Amarok - Rediscover Your Music!
DBusActivatable=true
Exec=amarok %U
GenericName=Audio Player
Icon=kplayer
MimeType=audio/aac;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/mpegurl;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/vorbis;audio/x-flac;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-oggflac;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-speex;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-wav;application/x-ogm-audio;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/ogg;
Name=Amarok
NoDisplay=false
Path=
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=amarok
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-DocPath=amarok/index.html
X-KDE-Keywords=music,podcast
X-KDE-Protocols=http
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

Comment: For a reason that I can't explain, if the command "amarok" is executed in the terminal, then the problem doesn't happen. 

Answer (score 1):

For some reason KDE (my case) creates an application shortcut called...

```
org.kde.amarok.desktop
```

... in the folder path...

```
/home/<YOUR_USER>/.local/share/applications
```

.

So I changed the name of this shortcut to...

```
Amarok.desktop
```

...and changed its content to...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Amarok - Rediscover Your Music!
Exec=amarok %F
Icon=amarok
MimeType=audio/aac;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/mpegurl;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/vorbis;audio/x-flac;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-oggflac;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-speex;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-wav;application/x-ogm-audio;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/ogg;
Name=Amarok
GenericName=Audio Player
NoDisplay=false
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

... and voilà!

Comment: Icon fixed but still clicking on icon gives me `The name org.kde.amarok was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: Check if the shortcut "Amarok.desktop" is present in the "plasma kickoff" along with the shortcut "org.kde.amarok.desktop". If so, the shortcut "org.kde.amarok.desktop" still exists somehow. ☺️

Comment: @Xaqron As root (`sudo su`) try to rename the file `org.kde.amarok.desktop` -> `mv "/usr/share/applications/org.kde.amarok.desktop" "/usr/share/applications/org.kde.amarok.desktop_BAK_20221111.1530.0"`. 